# Install PAM(Pluggable Authentication Modules) in Slackware 14.2

Tags: software-installation, pam, slackware, slackbuilds

PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) is a service that implements modular authentication modules. PAM is implemented as a set of shared objects that are loaded and executed when a program needs to authenticate a user.

Files for PAM are typically located in the `/etc/pam.d` directory. But the `pam.d` directory is non-existent within my Slackware system. Do I have to install it? If yes, what is the name of the package?

Comment: If you need PAM, you're better off picking a Linux distribution that supports it already. It's not easy to add it to one that doesn't, since you'd have to rebuild every package that needs to support it (essentially almost rebuilding the whole distro from scratch.) Every major Linux distribution supports PAM, so just pick one that suits you well. Good luck!

Comment: @filbranden  --> Thanks, unfortunately we have to work with Slackware

Comment: "have to" --> why? And why do you think you need PAM support, what kind of external authentication are you trying to integrate? Everywhere in the system or just one specific daemon?

Answer (score 3):

There is no PAM package in Slackware. It forces to many constraints on system (just like ie Gnome), and Slackware idea is to have modular system where packages can be easily replaced by user/admin.

There is also no unofficial package on https://slackbuilds.org/ , sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what alternative module can I use for authentication?

Comment: Time has passed - as of May 2020 Slackware-current includes PAM (no longer just in testing) and it should hopefully be in the next stable release after 14.2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this implementation of PAM on Slackware

http://www.slackware.com/~vbatts/pam/